# Can not populate tableview cells in side menu

Tags: swift, uitableview, menubar

I'm creating a Side-menu that will come out from the left. This menu has a tableview and each cell will present a new ViewController when pressed.

I want to access this Side-menu from all view controllers so it looks the same no matter in which view controller I am.

My guess is that this has something to do with the `delegate` and `datasource` but I can't set them to `self` . At least I don't know where

My Side-menu:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "SideMenuCell"

class SideMenu: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let menuItems = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    let blackView = UIView()

    let tableview: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.backgroundColor = .white
        table.separatorColor = .clear
        return table
    }()

    let container: UIView = {
       let con = UIView()
        con.backgroundColor = Colors.main
        return con
    }()

    @objc func showSettings() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            let menuWidth = window.frame.width * 0.7

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addTapGestureRecognizer {

                self.handleDismiss()
            }

            tableview.register(MenuOptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            window.addSubview(container)
            window.addSubview(tableview)

            tableview.anchor(left: container.leftAnchor, bottom: container.bottomAnchor, right: container.rightAnchor, height: window.frame.height * 0.85)

            container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 32, width: 0, height: window.frame.height)

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.blackView.alpha = 1
                self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: window.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)

        }

    }

    func handleDismiss() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.blackView.alpha = 0
                self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 32, width: 0, height: window.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MenuOptionCell
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
//        cell.iconImageView.image  = image
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
}
```

and the Custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class MenuOptionCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Mark: - Properties

    let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.text = "Sample Text"
        return label
    }()

    // Mark: - Init

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = .clear
        selectionStyle = .none

        addSubview(iconImageView)
        addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        iconImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
        descriptionLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: iconImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)

    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

when I press the left navigationbarButton the menu comes out and I can see the tableview, but all the cells are empty.

I want the cells to contain

- One
- Two
- Three
- Four
- Five

The idea with the container is to give som space to the top from the tableview where I could put som other information maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `self` as `delegate` and `dataSource` in `SideMenu` view controller's `showSettings` method

```
tableview.register(MenuOptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
tableview.delegate = self
tableview.datasource = self
```

Comment: I did this and can see in the "Debug view hierarchy" that the cells are there. But the textlabels are still not showing. Maybe something wrong with the anchors?

Comment: @maniponken It seems you have a `UIView extension` method called `anchor`. Show that method

Comment: @maniponken And use print statements in tableview numberofrows, cellforrow methods and confirm these methods are called

Comment: @maniponken check iconImageView, descriptionLabel frame in view hierarchy

Comment: The ```anchor``` function is too long. to post here, but something like this: 

func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingTop: CGFloat? = 0, paddingLeft: CGFloat? = 0, paddingBottom: CGFloat? = 0, paddingRight: CGFloat? = 0, width: CGFloat? = nil, height: CGFloat? = nil) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop!).isActive = true
        }  and so on...

Comment: print statements: 
numberOfRows is called 4 times
cellForRow is called 5 times

Comment: @maniponken print statement in cellfor row called? Have you checked iconImageView, descriptionLabel frame in view hierarchy

Comment: iconImageView and descriptionLabel are not shown in view hierarchy

Comment: @maniponken in view hierarchy select cell. Now select the label or image view from top navigation bar. Now check its frame and constraints

Comment: Ok not sure if this is what you mean but this is what I found (for the label):
label.bottom = project.MenuOptionCell.bottom @ 1000
label.height = 19.3333(content size)
label.width = 30(content size)
label.left = imageView.right @ 1000
label. right = project.MenuOptionCell.right @ 1000
label.top = project.MenuOptionCell @ 1000

Comment: Oh, I'm not using storyboards so I don't get that

Comment: this is what I get (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Comment: I was missing the frame of the label and image. I can see the items in the cell now. Thank you so much